# How to add dynamic information using the react-three-fiber library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

developers, good evening, I was using the react-three-fiber library, at the moment I have only been able to create simple 3d models, my question is:

Has anyone made these models using this library have dynamic information?

For example, if they had a planet as a 3d model and when it was over Mexico, a label would appear that says "Mexico" or something like that. Any advice or guidance is appreciated.